# Why does my terminal show -bash: /usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, drivers

```
-bash: /usr/share/modules/init/sh: No such file or directory
```

When I open up my terminal this appears first. I was trying to install lmod, and I think this might be a result due to that. How do I remove it ?

Comment: It's likely something that has been added to your `~/.bashrc` or similar file.

Comment: Can you type `cat ~/.bashrc` in another terminal and paste the output to your question? if you right click terminal and select 'preferences', you can create another profile and specify '/bin/zsh'  as the command. That will let you get around bash completely, for the time being.

Comment: You can also hold `ctrl+shift+F2` for tty. There is a separate terminal on every F key from 2-6. `ctrl+shift+F1` will bring you back.

Comment: Here is the output for `cat ~/ .bashrc` : https://jpst.it/2yDPb

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

As per [this](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/030_installing.html), installation of `lmod` probably changed one or more of the files in `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

You could try checking this (e.g., with the last modification date), and then look for the culprit.

Some info you could post to help:

1. The contents of "suspicious" files among those referred to.
2. The sequence of commands you used to install `lmod`. You could get this if you have `history` enabled.
3. An exact copy of everything you get when launching a terminal, including possibly the prompt.

---

From a terminal, execute `bash`. You will likely see the same error message.
If so, you can execute (preferably from a new terminal) `bash -x -v`. The options are:

```
  -v  Print shell input lines as they are read.
  -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
```

This way you would be able to identify the culprit of the error message.

Comment: Can you still use bash? If you are in ps2-4 ( cursor but no $, possibly a  > ) you may be able to get around it with `CONTROL + c` . Remember also that there are multiple bash versions. If all else fails, you can reset the $TERM variable in .bashrc.

Comment: `bash` doesn't return any output. But `bash - x -v` does, but the output is pretty long. I am not sure how to find the error there.

Comment: @PranavSatheesh - 
1) Can you successfully execute commands (e.g., `ls -l`) in the prompt you get with `bash`?
2) Output of `bash - x -v` can be long. Can you spot the error message within it? You may copy all that output into a text editor and search. Please post the 10 lines above and 10 lines after the error message.

Comment: I tried searching for the error message in `bash - x -v`  output, but couldn't find it . Here's the output in txt file : https://justpaste.it/4zzpd

Comment: I also tried `ls  /etc/profile.d/` to see what's going on there. I can see the modules.sh file there: https://justpaste.it/24gvi